# Error 404 con ficheros creados por la aplicación en Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, error404

A ver si me podéis echar una mano. Tengo un formulario con el que subo una imagen. El archivo lo puedo ver y aparentemente todo está correcto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos los archivos de las 10:44 vienen de hacer un git clone. El archivo de las 10:55 proviene del formulario. Puedo acceder a todos ellos, excepto al de las 10:55 que me da un error 404 haga lo que haga.

Más datos: lo tengo dockerizado y la carpeta que os muestro es la que sirve los archivos realmente.

Dejo también la configuración de nginx, por si es de utilidad:

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/public;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
# set client body size to 16M #
client_max_body_size 16M;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido pero nada. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Cómo es que intentas acceder al archivo?

Comment: Directamente con su URL. Por ejemplo, ahora mismo, un archivo con el que me pasa eso, que es equivalente al de las 10:55 que comento, es el de la ruta: http://167.99.33.61/images/users/11608893733.jpg 
Sin embargo, otro archivo que viene de haber hecho git clone sí se puede ver con el mismo tipo de ruta: http://167.99.33.61/images/users/11608797423.jpg 
Dentro de la aplicación pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Puede que se deba a que el link esté roto, por eso sólo funcionan los que ya estaban y no los nuevos. Intenta eliminando la carpeta y volviendo a crearla con el commando php artisan:storage link

Comment: @JonatanLavado, creo que tiene mucho sentido eso. Soy nuevo en Laravel y no sé muy bien a qué carpeta te refieres que elimine. Investigando un poco he visto que puede ser relevante mi configuración y no sé si mi estructura de carpetas. En filesystems.php tengo esto: 
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
         ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]

Comment: Mi aplicación está en: /var/www. Las imágenes que me dan problemas las pretendo almacenar en /var/www/public/images/users. Las que ya estaban ahí se ven, pero las nuevas no. Y en /var/www/storage/app no hay nada, ni antes ni después de subir imágenes con el formulario.

Por otra parte, también tengo esto en filesystem: 

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

Comment: A lo que me refería es que debes eliminar el fólder dentro de la carpeta app/public/storage que contiene tus imágenes. No borres nada de la carpeta public/storage, ya que cuando hagas php artisan storage:link se volverá a copiar todo dentro de esa carpeta public.

Comment: Perdón por mi ignorancia, pero no lo termino de entender. Tengo una carpeta /var/www/storage/app. Dentro de ella no hay nada. Y después tengo una carpeta /var/www/public/images/users que es donde realmente estoy subiendo las imágenes y no se ven. Sólo las que venían de hacer git clone se ven. No tengo ni app/public/storage ni public/storage.

Comment: Toda carpeta que se mencioné en Laravel siempre es tomado desde la raiz de tu aplicación. Aquí no debes tomar /var/www, debes ir directamente a la raíz de tu aplicación y desde allí ir a la carpeta public y eliminar tus imágenes, si has hecho todo bien, cuando ejecutes el comando storage:link se creará nuevamente ese fólder, pero si no estás seguro es mejor que hagas un backup antes de eliminar cualquier cosa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, di con la solución: era un error mío de novato. En la configuración de docker no estaba persistiendo los datos de manera que las imágenes sólo subían al contenedor de la aplicación, por lo que no era visible para Nginx. La solución ha sido persistir estos datos en el host y habilitar el acceso a éste desde Nginx y desde la aplicación:

```
services:

  app:
    container_name: laravel_app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: development/app.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage
      - ./public/images:/var/www/public/images
    env_file: '.env.dev'
    environment:
      - "DB_HOST=database"
      - "REDIS_HOST=cache"

  web:
    container_name: nginx_server
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: development/web.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./storage/logs/:/var/log/nginx
      - ./public/images:/var/www/public/images
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Simplemente añadí la segunda línea en "volumes" y listo. Por si a algún otro novato como yo le puede ser útil. Gracias @Jonatan Lavado por tu ayuda!!